# Q: [WEATHER] How can I view example Alert response data?

Tags: here-api

I need to design a program around the possibility of severe weather alerts. With that said, I need to know the structure of the alert object returned. The [example](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/auto_weather/weather-forecast-alerts) in the reference displays an empty array, which doesn't help me much. I can't exactly wait around for an alert to occur; any ideas?

Comment: What about looking at the reference documentation itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the attributes in alerts here - https://developer.here.com/documentation/weather/topics/resource-type-alert-items.html.

Alerts is an array consisting objects of AlertItemsType which have the below values:

1. Type of alert
   We have 36 support global types which can be viewed here - https://developer.here.com/documentation/weather/topics/supported-alert-types.html
2. Description of the alert
3. The TimeSegmentType type defines the attributes this element can have.

For example currently, we see weather alerts for the below query. Replace app_id and ap_code values with actuals.

```
https://weather.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json?product=alerts&app_id=xxxx&app_code=yyyyy&name=Bodenseekreis
```

[image]